# Shortening my questions code

Tags: c#, beginner, url

Is there any other way to shorten this code without sacrificing readability?  I am fairly new to C#, let alone programming, and I wanted to know if this is as short as this code can possibly become.  Feedback would be greatly welcomed.

Side note: was `Questions.Questask` used properly here, or could there have been a better way?

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name = "";
        while (name.ToLower() != "none")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Are you Kydd,Leo,Jay,Sha, or Zigg");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            if (name.ToLower() == "kydd")
                Question.Questask("Input question here", "Kquestion","Link");
            else if (name.ToLower() == "leo")
                Question.Questask("Input question here", "Lquestion", "Link");
            else if (name.ToLower() == "jay")
                Question.Questask("Input question here", "Jquestion", "Link");
            else if (name.ToLower() == "sha")
                Question.Questask("Input question here", "Squestion", "Link");
            if (name.ToLower() == "zigg")
                Question.Questask("Input question here", "Zquestion", "Link");
       }
    }

    class Question
    {
        public static void Questask(string question, string questAnswer, string url)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(question);
            questAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (questAnswer.ToLower() == "yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are right!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stick the result of ToLower() into a new variable.  You'll only have to call ToLower() once that way.

Comment: For any non-trivial application, the questions and names would be stored in some sort of data repository like an XML file or database, not emblazoned into the actual code itself.

Comment: You could place "Input Question Here" in a string instead of repeating it many times. Also, do you really want a Console.ReadKey() at the class code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote this for you, making it easier to understand and making it a little more efficient (although, the size is just a tad bigger then your original). Hopefully it makes a little more sense and you can ask any questions if you need to:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var names = new List<NameClass>
        {
            new NameClass {Name = "Kydd", Answer = "Kquestion"},
            new NameClass {Name = "Leo", Answer = "Lquestion"},
            new NameClass {Name = "Jay", Answer = "Jquestion"},
            new NameClass {Name = "Sha", Answer = "Squestion"},
            new NameClass {Name = "Zigg", Answer = "Zquestion"}
        };

        string name = "";
        while (name.ToLower() != "none")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Are you Kydd,Leo,Jay,Sha, or Zigg");
            name = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            var a = names.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Name.ToLower() == name);
            if (a != null)
            {
                Questask(a.Question, a.Answer, a.Url);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Questask(string question, string questAnswer, string url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(question);
        questAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (questAnswer.ToLower() == "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are right!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
        }
    }

    public class NameClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public NameClass()
        {
            Question = "Input question here";
            Url = "Link";
        }
    }
}
```

The beauty of this code is that you don't need a bunch of `if` statements. If you need to add more, simply add one more line of code in the names definition.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what exactly did you change.

Comment: Thank you for this Beauty of a Code It will help me better understand the use of classes which I still struggle with. Just one Question What exactly does names.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Name.ToLower() == name) line of do kinda stumped on it

Comment: It's a LINQ expression that returns the first NameClass in the list names that has a Name.ToLower that equals name or a default value (null).

Answer (score 1):

When I need a simple [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) I'll use a `Dictionary`. This can drastically reduce code by cutting repetition.

Note the use of `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` for [`comparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx) to do away with the `String.ToLower` calls.

```
private static readonly IDictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> NamesDictionary =
    new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
        { "kydd", Tuple.Create("question 1", "link1") },
        { "zydd", Tuple.Create("question 2", "link2") },
        ...
    };

private static void DoSomething(string name)
{
    Tuple<string, string> questionAndLinkTuple;

    if (!NamesDictionary.TryGetValue(name, out questionAndLinkTuple))
        return;

    var question = questionAndLinkTuple.Item1;
    var link = questionAndLinkTuple.Item2;

    Question.AskQuestion("Input answer here", question, link);
}
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that renames `Questask` to `AskQuestion` :) Actually since the class is `Question` and the method is `static`, a perhaps even better name would be simply `Ask()`...

Comment: @retailcoder I didn't bother with it in my answer, but a more complex example I could understand the need for a `Question` class. OP's example would have been just fine without `Question` and instead have a static `Program.AskQuestion`.

Answer (score 1):

I like icemanind's answer, but to give an alternate point of view -- sometimes you just need to get it done.

```
string[] names = {"kydd","leo","jay","sha","zigg");
if (Array.IndexOf(names, name.ToLower())>-1){
   Question.Questask("Input question here", 
       string.Format("{0}question",name[0].ToUpper()),"Link");
}
```